# Mp3 without mp3 extension not playing on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ios5, html5-audio

The following fiddle works on my pc but not on my iphone:

http://jsfiddle.net/t4j7a/

The player src is being set to something of the form:

```
http://apifree.forvo.com/audio/3d3j2o2c311k2k383b332c211m3d271o32273i211b3a252j3e3m2h3c1m3b2c2o372c3o333c311p25331n2l1n3p252o3j1i392i2c3832372o3d1i2e32371o2m2m2j2g3e3o1i2g2o211m281b2g243b3q2826221l2i1k2h1t1t_251o293n2m262p2k3l3g2q3q3i1f32222j3e292i352h1t1t
```

Is there any limitations to what iphone can handle which is causing paths of this form not to work?

Comment: Because this is a Flash player!!! Flash is not supported on iOS devices !

Comment: @GilbertOOl No I'm using a html5 player in my fiddle and I'm setting the src of it to the mp3 address I get via the ajax request.